# MySQL: Update table column with id from other table by string compare

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with a `VARCHAR` column called "name1" and "name2":

table1:

```
id   |  name1
1    |  xyz
2    |  foo
3    |  barfoo
4    |  xchad
```

table2:

```
id   |  id_table1  | name2
1    |    NULL     | xchad
2    |    NULL     | foo
3    |    NULL     | hade
4    |    NULL     | bar
```

I want to update the column `id_table1` of `table2` with the respective id from `table1` where the rows `name1` and `name2` match.
For example  in table2 the first row should be updated with `4` in column `id_table1` since `'xchad' = 'xchad'`.

A join simply takes too much time with the string compare.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name2 = t1.name1
SET t2.id_table1 = t1.id
```

With indexes on `table1(name1)` and `table2(name2)`, this should perform efficiently.

An alternative is to use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET t2.id_table1 = (
    SELECT t1.name1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.name1 = t2.id_table1
)
```

Please note that this second solution does require each name in `table2` to have a unique match in `table1`.